# Cannot not figure these errors

Tags: html

**Line 80, Column 16: End tag form seen, but there were open elements.**      
**Line 42, Column 27: Unclosed element**                    fieldset.
**Line 80, Column 16: Cannot recover after last error.**

```
<p><form action="http://ctec.clark.edu/CTEC122/scripts/form_echo.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fieldset2">
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
            <div>
                <label id="label1" for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" size="50" required>

                <label id="label2" for="street">Street:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" size="50">

                <label id="label3" for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="50">

                <label id="label4" for="state">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="50">

                <label id="label5" for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" size="50">

                <label id="label6" for="homephone">Home Phone:</label>  
                    <input type="text" name="homephone" id="homephone" size="50">

                <label id="label7" for="cellphone">Cell Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cellphone" id="cellphone" size="50">

                <label id="label8" for="email">E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50">

                <label id="label9" for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <input id="dob" type="date" name="dob">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                <label id="label10" for="radio">Gender:</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>
                    Male
                    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>
                    Female
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </fieldset>
```

Comment: `<form><fieldset></form></fieldset>`. Also, "Cannot not figure these errors" is amusing.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you have such form structure:

```
<form action="http://ctec.clark.edu/CTEC122/scripts/form_echo.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fieldset2">
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <div></div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

See the problem? You closed `fieldset` after `form`. Should be:

```
<form action="http://ctec.clark.edu/CTEC122/scripts/form_echo.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fieldset2">
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <div></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

Edit: the unclosed `p` tag may not be a problem. According to W3C spec on [syntax tag omission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission).

> A `p` element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, you use the "p"-Tag. You never close it, if i see it correctly. And you swapped the closing fileset- and form-tag.

Comment: According to W3C spec, closing `p` tag can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing `</form>` tag before `</fieldset>`. Place `</form>` tag at end and also make sure to close `</p>` tag.